# Change jre7 to jre5 Windows XP + Java Control Panel

Tags: windows-xp, version, java

I know that the simplest way to do it is manually change `PATH` variable but what could be the reason if this change doesn't make any difference?
This is my System variable Path:

> C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files\Rational\common;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\maven-2.0.11\bin\;c:\jboss\5\bin\;c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_21\bin\

and this is my console output after java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't know where variable `%SystemRoot%` stores this value but I don't see it in System variables.

I have ready installed both jre7 and jre5 but I must change for jre5 for comparability reason. How to do this? Do I have to uninstall jre7 and install jre5?
How does the [Java control panel](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/javacontrolpanel.png) work ?

How do I use this tool and what is the effect if I unchecked some of the product?
This should be some simple fault in my site but I can't find it.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall. Most program use the PATH and JAVA_HOME env variables.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I ended up uninstalling java 7. Neither changing the env variables or disabling from java control panel worked.

Comment: Daft question but did you close and re-open the command prompt?  Also there are system level environment variables and user level variables.  Make sure the PATH/JAVA_HOME ones are correct wherever they exist.  User level over-rides the system level.

Comment: To respond your question " did you close and re-open the command prompt?" - yes I do, even I restarted the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On later versions of Java (6+, I think), the Java installer copies an executable named 'java.exe' into a Windows system folder (e.g., c:\windows\system32). From what I can tell, the executable just calls the version of java it was installed with. Because it's in a Windows system folder, that 'java.exe' is the first thing found on the path. Windows never searches far enough to check whatever Java install path you added.

So, you could either remove the executables from the Windows folder, or try moving the Java install folder to the beginning of the list of folders on the path, like this:

> **c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_21\bin\;** C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token
>   Common;**%SystemRoot%\system32**;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program
>   Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Rational\common;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\maven-2.0.11\bin\;c:\jboss\5\bin\;

I'm guessing that on 64 bit versions, the location of the executable will be different, but a search for 'java.exe' should help you find where they've hidden them.

Comment: +1 so if you install java6 and later keeping java6, we install java7, `C:\windows\system32\java.exe` will be replaced by `java7's java.exe`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of my office, but your advice looks rational. I'll try tomorrow.